# Help finding and installing drivers for ASUS VivoBook E200HA and Asus B53E

Tags: drivers, sound, keyboard, asus

I've installed Ubuntu on one of my laptops but I couldn't get the keyboard and sound card installed (a plug-in USB keyboard works).

My laptop is an ASUS VivoBook E200HA. Below is a [link on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01A9ECXRY/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I would also want to install it on my other laptop [ASUS B53E](https://www.pcgarage.ro/notebook-laptop/asus/b53e-so216x-core-i7-2640m-28ghz-8gb-750gb-hd-3000-win-7-pro-black/), but I don't want to have the same problem.

What should I do?

Comment: The Asus VivoBook is the worse you can choose for Linux. Here's why: http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com.es/2016/10/running-ubuntu-on-intel-bay-trail-and.html . Forget about sound, the best you can do at the moment is to use a generic USB audio adapter; the keyboard and WiFi should work with the special ISO made by Linuxium. No problems are expected with the other one except, perhaps, the WiFi. If so, open a new question specifically for that and post the exact WiFi chipset it has.

Comment: Due to the processor, and the 2G memory, try booting to a Xubuntu or Lubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if things work better. If they do, install one of them.

Comment: @MichaelBay I have tried ubuntu 16.04 which didn't recognize the keyboard, not after testing the 17.04 the keyboard and pad worked flawlesly. I didn't have problems with other hardware except the sound card which everybody is waiting for an answer.I will use for the moment a £5 USB sound card (the laptop is just for web stuff, nothing to major).I have also tried Mint which had the same problems as Ubuntu. I have read somewhere that there in the near  future Ubuntu 17.10 might be coming so I will also try that maybe it gives a fix. Thanks -heynnema I am not to bothered about performance.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with this laptop, sorry. And with Linux you do not have to search for drivers as you might be used to from, say, Windows.

Why not? here are some general remarks:

Many hardware drivers are already part of the kernel, and you don't install them on your own. (It used to be more common in the 90s to install a kernel patch with some driver code yourself, but these days it is much less common.)

Some drivers can be made available as a loadable kernel module.

For some hardware, e.g. network cards, there are often a few alternative driver implementations available in the kernel, or as a loadable kernel module, and you can choose among them  to some extent. See directory /etc/modprobe, in particular /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist* files. There some modules have been explicitly DISabled for various reasons, usually because better implementations have become available.

At startup time you can give parameters to some drivers, enabling or disabling certain features, but this is also not that common.

Comment: So how does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks, I will see if any of these work, otherwise I will leave it untill a newer version is released maybe that will include a better support.

Comment: Unfortunatelly nothing worked for the sound card. Hopefully a newer version wil fix this.